# Unfamiliar C Syntax in the Declaration of Function

Tags: c, function

Currently looking at some C code that doesn't make any sense to me. What is (elementSize)? How am supposed to pass arguments to this static function? What is the name of this syntax style so I can learn more abour it?

```
static int torch_Tensor_(elementSize)(lua_State *L)
{
  luaT_pushinteger(L, THStorage_(elementSize)());
  return 1;
}
```

https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/generic/Tensor.c

This is the file I am trying to understand for reference.

Comment: `torch_Tensor_` and `THStorage_` are probably macros.  THStorage_ may be a  function which returns a function pointer.

Comment: Taken on its own, it is just a syntax error.  You can define a function that returns a pointer to a function (e.g. `signal()` in standard C), but not a function that returns a function (nor a function that returns an array, rather than a pointer).  If there are some macros to help (such as `#define torch_Tensor_(x) …` then it might compile, and you need to work out where `elementSize` is defined to know what is passed to the macro as an argument.  It looks like you'll need to study the headers provided with Lua.

Answer (score 4):

Normally

```
static int torch_Tensor_(elementSize)(lua_State *L)
```

would mean `torch_Tensor_` is a function that takes a single parameter called `elementSize` that has no type (?! - syntax error) and returns a function that takes a pointer to `lua_State` and returns an `int`. This is blatantly invalid (functions cannot return other functions).

But what's actually going on here is that `torch_Tensor_` is defined as a function-like macro, so before the compiler even sees this declaration, `torch_Tensor_(elementSize)` is replaced by something else.

In https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/Tensor.c there is

```
#include "general.h"

#define torch_Storage_(NAME) TH_CONCAT_4(torch_,Real,Storage_,NAME)
#define torch_Storage TH_CONCAT_STRING_3(torch.,Real,Storage)
#define torch_Tensor_(NAME) TH_CONCAT_4(torch_,Real,Tensor_,NAME)
#define torch_Tensor TH_CONCAT_STRING_3(torch.,Real,Tensor)

#include "generic/Tensor.c"
#include "THGenerateAllTypes.h"

#include "generic/Tensor.c"
#include "THGenerateHalfType.h"
```

with `TH_CONCAT_...` defined in `lib/TH/THGeneral.h.in`:

```
#define TH_CONCAT_STRING_3(x,y,z) TH_CONCAT_STRING_3_EXPAND(x,y,z)
#define TH_CONCAT_STRING_3_EXPAND(x,y,z) #x #y #z

#define TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(x,y,z,w) x ## y ## z ## w
#define TH_CONCAT_4(x,y,z,w) TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(x,y,z,w)
```

So `torch_Tensor_` is defined as a macro before `generic/Tensor.c` is included.

```
torch_Tensor_(elementSize)
```

expands to

```
TH_CONCAT_4(torch_,Real,Tensor_,elementSize)
```

which expands to

```
TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(torch_,...,Tensor_,elementSize)
```

`...` is a placeholder, not real code. `Real` is defined as a macro in the various `THGenerate*Type.h` files, so this line actually becomes

```
TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(torch_,char,Tensor_,elementSize)
TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(torch_,int,Tensor_,elementSize)
TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(torch_,float,Tensor_,elementSize)
...
```

depending on context. Anyway, the end result is a single identifier of the form

```
torch_charTensor_elementSize
torch_intTensor_elementSize
torch_floatTensor_elementSize
...
```

(one token).

The resulting function definition thus looks like e.g.

```
static int torch_charTensor_elementSize(lua_State *L)
{
    ...
}
```

depending on which context `generic/Tensor.c` was included in.

The reason things are done this way is to have what amounts to the same code, but for multiple different types. In C++ you would write a function template:

```
namespace torch {
    template<typename Real>
    static int Tensor_elementSize(lua_State *L) { ... }
}
```

But C has no templates (nor namespaces), so the only way to get "generic" code like this is to do it manually with macros and preprocessing tricks (and manually "decorating" names; e.g. the `elementSize` function for floats is really called `torch_floatTensor_elementSize`).

All we're really trying to do is abstract over a type parameter, here called `Real`.

Comment: I'm guessing that file is compiled multiple times, with `elementSize` defined to different values.  For example, if you defined it to 8, you would end up with `torch_RealTensor_8()`.

Comment: @nemequ No, the parameter is `Real`. `elementSize` is the name of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance! This helps a ton and I'll be going over it carefully to make sure I understand everything.

Comment: Wow, I finally sat down and digested the guide you wrote. It finally makes a ton of sense now. The only thing I am still left confused about is how the compiler knows that Real is a macro defined variable not Tensor_ or elementSize in the following piece of code TH_CONCAT_4(torch_,Real,Tensor_,elementSize)?

Comment: @btomtom5 The preprocessor simply performs macro expansion on all identifiers. In principle all of those names could be `#define`d as something else, but a quick search of the codebase shows that only `#define Real ...` appears in some files, so that's what the preprocessor replaces. Of course I'm assuming that `generic/Tensor.c` is only included in places where `#define Real ...` is active; otherwise it would remain as is.